# Mixpanel Flow .js Libray

Tags: mixpanel

Does anyone know if exists a .js library for website traffic visualization? I need something like Mixpanel Flow [photo1 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRJyP.jpg), [photo2 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DENsT.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you might like this link:

FYI - AFAIK this isn't an appropriate question for StackOverflow

[vizceral](https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check and probably this will help me.